# How to detect softkeyboard done button click in android select menu of phonegap app

Tags: android, events, cordova

This post is related to this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378676

Android select menu in a webview fires change event in every item click. I want do make that happen only after done button is clicked after changes.