# How to detect keyboard close event in android device with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, keyboard-events

I'm developing android application with *phonegap*. Currently I'm facing one problem with `inputbox` problem with specific HTC Android device and I have a solution for that. But  I need to know **when keyboard close event occurred**.

so my question is *how to detect keyboard close event with phonegap* or any plugins available to detect keyboard event for android device.?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen for keyboard open/close in Javascript/Sencha?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241492/how-to-listen-for-keyboard-open-close-in-javascript-sencha)

Comment: @Derek i have used focus/blur event for that but still not working with specific HTC device as i have mentioned.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8241633/283863).

Comment: i have implemented blue event for textbox but when trying to close keyboard blur event is not fired.

Comment: Stands to reason, the text field doesn't blur when the keyboard is closed usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Phonegap, but I did some rudimentary Google searches like 'phonegap android hide keyboard event' and came across these two relevant posts from a few months ago.

First one is right here on SO:  [Android SoftKeyboardDetect: Ignore this event what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333689/android-softkeyboarddetect-ignore-this-event-what-does-it-mean).  It looks like if you drop down to "native" Java(...) Android tries to make this available.

This other one, [Re: [PhoneGap] Re: SoftKeyboardDetect(328): Ignore](http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2012-02/msg01862.html) on a phonegap-oriented website seems to suggest that the phonegap implementation or the SoftKeyboardDetect code is to blame.

I have Android code written in Java where it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem for iPhone app development with phonegap. I have fixed the problem with the following way.

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").
bind("blur", function(e) {
 window.scrollTo(0.0);
 loaded();
});
```

You can detect the close event with 'blur' action.

Comment: If you reference an extrenal link with the solution, please also add the solution in your answer. This way the solutions remains if the referenced website should go offline. The credit is still given to the original solution. Nothing is more frustrating than finding a dead link after reading "I found the perfect solution for your problem here: <dead link>".

Comment: the huge problem with this is that what's inside the bind function executes before the keyboard closes (at lest reproduceable on ios 7)

Answer (score -2):

I use :

```
 inputElement.bind("closeKeyboard", function() {
             //do something
 });
```